# If IV-V are most related to the tonic are the other chords just substitution and or flavor?

Tags: chord-progressions

Using a major scale do the ii, iii, vi, and viidim diatonic chords have a purpose besides extra 'flavor'.

Comment: Did Schenker put you up to this? :)

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question seems to be that the only chords that have a 'purpose' are those that are closely related to the tonic. But taking that logic to its extreme, we wouldn't use any other chords at all apart from the tonic - after all, the tonic is most closely related to itself, so why use the IV and V? They are purposeless, compared to the I....

Ultimately, all chords are partly there for flavor - even the IV and the V. The other triads -  ii, iii, vi, and vii° - give us more flavours, more possible motions, more options for voice leading... just more options in general. And that's also true of techniques like modulation and chord borrowing.

flavor *is* the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Movement from one chord to another is often characterized by "strength" and this is taken loosely to mean "how strongly it the first chord attracted to the second" which doesn't really help since that may seem very subjective.  Movement among the set {I, IV, V} is in some sense the strongest movement.  More specifically the movement V7 --> I is the "strongest" of all and is called the authentic cadence.  IV --> I is also strong but not as much so, referred to as the Amen cadence.

In fact one can get away with only using I and V or V7 for the most part, avoiding IV all together.  In fact a goo amount of classical music gravitates towards these two chords.  If you play on only these harmony gets pretty boring, and as another answer mentions the progression should set up "drama".  If all you have is I and V or V7 all you get is ending after ending and no pause to appreciate the build up.

To add to this each chord in the diatonic scale (with one exception) is the V of the next chord a 4th above it (confusing way to say it).  If you play the chords in diatonic 4ths you get the famous circle progression,

I --> IV --> vii --> iii --> vi --> ii --> V --> I

Using substitutions you can map this into a variant of I IV V, but the above progression has a distinct movement that a simple I IV V does not.  Using chords that are close to the tonic is great for ending a phrase but all the other chords help build the story that leads to the ending.

From a functional point of view perhaps they have no other purpose except "flavor", but what's wrong with that?  You need flavor.

Chords can be grouped as follows {I, vi, iii}, {IV, ii, vi}, {V, iii, vii (when V7 is used)},  Any chord in the group can replace the other chords in the group.  That doesn't mean they all sound the same.  It just means that movement within the group is less dramatic.  Rather than jumping from I to IV you can smoothly walk to vi which connects them.  Etc.

Comment: `Chords can be grouped as follows {I, vi, iii}, {IV, ii, vi}, {V, iii, vii (when V7 is used)}` wow, never seen this before. fascinating

Comment: Look at functional harmony, chord substitutions, and polychord theory

Comment: What I learned about common practice period harmony from my music theory lessons says that the V-iii chord progression is forbidden and that iii should really be grouped with IV, ii, and vi instead, despite what you say.

Comment: iii is the relative minor of V.  It is a suitable replacement for the V producing a 6 chord.  Moving from one to the other would be not much more than an inversion, perfectly normal.  Moving to the I would be a little empty as there isn't a strong cadence.

Answer (score 4):

In a certain sense, "yes."

But what you hint at is *functional harmony*: whose functions are *pre-dominant* (subdominant) `IV`, *dominant* `V` and *tonic* `I`.

That leaves the four other diatonic chords `ii`, `viio`, `vi`, and `iii`.

`viio` gets grouped easily with `V` as both contain the leading tone and they can be viewed as the two parts that make a dominant seventh chord `V7`.

`ii` gets grouped with `IV` as subdominants, and `vi` with `I`, and both can be easily understood as *relative minors*. `vi` acting as a kind of tonic is one way of explaining the *deceptive cadence* `V vi`.

`iii` is the odd one out - and it's comparatively rare in common practice harmony - I've seen it grouped with the dominant and tonic by different people.

German music theory gets into these relationships in detail.

So, you can fulfill the basic flow of functional harmony - pre-dominant, dominant, tonic - with either the *primary* chords `IV V I` or with a *secondary* chord to provide the pre-dominant function `ii6 V I`.

What's the difference? "Color" seems like a good way to describe the difference between the qualities of an *inverted* and *minor* `ii6` and a *root position* and *major* `IV` that both act functionally as the same thing. A bit more technical word could be "unstable" for the inverted `ii6`. It's a bit lighter and tremulous than `IV`. Many words could apply, but the important thing is recognizing the difference as a kind of subcategory or the larger category of pre-dominant/subdominant. Different, but not totally different.

If you think of them in terms of substitution, I think you want to look at the expressive potential of the options and use what suits you. Instead of thinking of the substitutions are merely interchangeable, realize one option might be more appropriate than another. For example, `IV V I` may sound more resolute than `ii6 V I`.

Comment: I've seen iii grouped with the other pre-dominant chords such as IV and ii a lot more often in my music theory lessons than with the tonic or dominant chords. My lessons said that the iii chord doesn't behave like a dominant at all.

Comment: @Dekkadeci this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(music)#German_functional_theory summarizes the German theory I mentioned. But, I too learned US theory where `iii` would be a pre-dominant, even if just by elimination, it's isn't a dominant, not a tonic. To be honest this matter of `iii` is the main thing I don't get about the German theory.

Answer (score 2):

As one of my teachers would put it, harmony is a tool for painting the drama. Effective story telling has conflict, tension, mystery, and suspense. You could give us the ending of your story in one line, but what's the fun in that!